# Query all items which belong to same model based on article number

Tags: search, query, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I want to create a query which retrieves all items which belong to same model, based on their article number. Every item have an article number which can be something like I-12V2 which is standard headset, RI-12V2 is red headset, BI-12V2 is blue headset and so on, if the user inserts an article number into search input, it must return all headsets. article numbers has differnt format for different type of items and I have used Content Search Web part to show items.

**updated:**

articleNumber is a managed property which for headsets it can contain following values.

standard Headset which is black, articleNumber = I-12V2

Blue headset, articleNumber = BI-12V2

Red headset, articleNumber = RI-12V2

other series of products for examlpe laptops have another articleNumber for example L-ew53 or LB-ew43

Now the user inserts a articleNumber in the textbox to search for a product, If aritcleNumber belongs to a laptop I want to retrieve all laptops, if it belongs to a headset I want to retrieve all headsets. The problem is there is no real pattern for articleNumbers.

Comment: What is your question, can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: +1 Can you detail the steps you have tried? Show the Managed Properties you are working with?